# OpenDDS participants could not discovery each other

Tags: tcp, data-distribution-service, opendds

Rcently, I try to communicate by using OpenDDS-3.12. I want to communicate other two hosts which located other WAN. But, participants could not discovery each other. How can I solve this problem??

Here is my communication enviroments:

I have two hosts. HostA and Host B is my Destktop(Ubuntu 16.04). Also, two hosts has public IP address(visible) and disable firewall. I already checked whether the specific port number was available by telnet command.

I used OpenDDS-3.12 and $OpenDDS_HOME/tests/DCPS/Messenger 's example.

In HostA, enable

```
$ DCPSInfoRepo -ORBListenEndpoints iiop://:12345
```

Subscriber operate like this:

```
$ ./subscriber -DCPSInfoRepo <HostA's IP>:12345 -DCPSConfigFile sub_multicast.ini
```

In HostB,
Directory is same and publisher operate like this:

```
$ ./publisher -DCPSInfoRepo <HostA's IP>:12345 -DCPSConfigFile pub_multicast.ini
```

Publisher's return error message here:

```
# ./publisher -DCPSInfoRepo <HostA's IP>:12345 -DCPSConfigFile pub_multicast.ini
Starting publisher
(8921|139698127107904) NOTICE: using DCPSInfoRepo value from command option (overrides value if it's in config file).
Starting publisher with 1 args
Reliable DataWriter
Creating Writer
Starting Writer
(8921|139697959323392) WARNING: SynWatchdog[transport=3]::on_timeout: timed out waiting on remote peer: 0x30c5d67200000007 local: 0x30c5d67200000005
```

What is the proper configuration to discover other each WAN host??

Hope you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rtps_uni.ini for both publisher and subscriber